# Make Fields editable when Checkbox is ticked SIEBEL CRM

Tags: checkbox, crm, siebel

This is my question regarding SIEBEL CRM, I have a checkbox and some fields that are read-only. I want to know how would the logic be if I want the fields to be editable when the checkbox is ticked ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

check about user property business component FieldReadOnlyField

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).